# Stored ENUM is displayed as a string

Tags: php, enums, phpmyadmin

I have an `ENUM` stored in PHPMYADMIN which allows the numbers 1-10.

I'm trying to find out how that number can be converted to a string which the user can see, an example is;

1=London

2=Spain

3=France

4=Germany

etc...

The obvious way would be to do an if statement for each something like

```
if ENUM == 1 then STRING == "London"
if ENUM == 2 then STRING == "Spain"
```

but I was wondering if there was a similar way of doing this or if I just need to do 10 if statements. I've tried to look online but no helpful tutorials.
    Thanks (Sorry i've had to submit the question as code, stackoverflow wouldnt allow me to post it otherwise for some reason)

Comment: You need to create another table as a look up for those values. Or just create an array in php.

Comment: How would i do this, sorry i'm fairly new to coding

Comment: Are the values (London, Spain...) going to be changed or are they fixed?

Comment: no they wont be able to be changed, they will remain the same,

Comment: This question lays out some simple options for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/344104/whats-quicker-an-array-lookup-including-array-build-or-an-if-stack

Comment: I would recommend defining constants or, better yet, use an [enum](https://github.com/myclabs/php-enum).

Comment: Another example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46266309/simplify-if-statements-used-to-determine-response-for-different-file-types

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an efficient/clean/professional way of doing it:

```
$enum = 1; // The value fetched from the database

$cities = array(
    '1'=>'London', 
    '2'=>'Spain', 
    '3'=>'France', 
    '4'=>'Germany'
); // Array of cities
// Make sure there is a city with the given key
if(isset($cities[$enum])){
    echo $cities[$enum];
}
```

But it is also advisable to store the cities in another database table.

Comment: Thank you very much, i will use this method for now so at least i can get it up and running and with more practice hopefully i can get the cities stored in a database table, Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Matt do you know how to accept an answer on StackOverflow?

Comment: Sorry no, first time asking a question on here.